# Apache Guacamole + Nginx Proxy Manager = SyntaxError

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running Apache Guacamole inside Docker and I want to make it publicly accessible using Nginx Proxy Manager.

This is the Docker Stack for Guacamole:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local

services:
  guacamole:
    image: guacamole/guacamole:latest
    container_name: guacamole_server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - guacd
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOSTNAME=mysql
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole
      - MYSQL_USER=guacamole
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - GUACD_HOSTNAME=guacd
      - GUACD_PORT=4822

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: guacamole_mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=guacamole
      - MYSQL_USER=guacamole
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-u", "root", "--password=guacamole"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  guacd:
    image: guacamole/guacd:latest
    container_name: guacamole_guacd
    restart: always
```

When I access Guacamole via it's local IP on port 8080 everything works perfectly fine.

Then I added a new Proxy Host to Nginx Proxy Manager with the following configuration:

Details:

- Domain Name: (something)
- Scheme: http
- IP: 192.168.123.123
- Port: 8080
- Cache Assets: disabled
- Block Common Exploits: enabled
- Websockets Support: enabled
- Access List: Publicly Accessible

SSL:

- Force SSL: enabled
- HSTS Enabled: enabled
- HTTP/2 Support: enabled
- HSTS Subdomains: disabled

Custom Locations:

- (none)

Advanced:

- (nothing)

So far it still works perfectly fine.

If I now change the configuration:
(Grabbed that from https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/104)

Custom Locations:

- Location: /
- Scheme: http
- Forward Hostname: 192.168.123.123/guacamole/
- Port: 8080
- Advanced: (nothing)

Then I get a blank page, but all the source code gets loaded and all requests are status 200.
In the console of the browser I see:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

The exact same happens when I instead of the 'Custom Locations' configuration I make my own advanced configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://$server:$port/guacamole/;
}
```

I also tried different configurations here, but I always got that error. I didn't find any hint in a long online research.

Comment: Did you try the official documentation of Apache Guacamole? https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/proxying-guacamole.html
Proxying worked for me using Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use no 'Custom Location'.

Put this in Advanced:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.123.123:8080/guacamole/;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /;
    access_log off;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe I had the same problem trying to configure guacamole and recently stumbled upon a solution.

For the Details:

- Domain Name: example.com
- Scheme: http
- IP: 192.168.123.123
- Port: 8080
- Cache Assets: disabled
- Block Common Exploits: enabled
- Websockets Support: enabled
- Access List: Publicly Accessible

Then, SSL:

- Force SSL: enabled
- HSTS Enabled: enabled
- HTTP/2 Support: enabled
- HSTS Subdomains: disabled

So far so good, guacamole would be accessed from example.com/guacamole.

In order to forward the subdirectory so that example.com points to example.com/guacamole the Custom Locations should be:

- Location: /
- Scheme: http
- Forward Hostname: example.com/guacamole
- Port: 8080

Meaning, you actually forward the existing domain subdirectory not the actual server IP. I do not know the exact details, but this worked for me after a lot of other tries.

Comment: This did result in a 502 error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/501663)